# Laravel Request hasFile returns false despite file actually attached

Tags: laravel, file-upload

I'm using a nice HTML template which features a preview of the picture selected by my HTML file input. This is the HTML:

```
<div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                                        <div class="fileinput-new img-thumbnail text-center">
                                            <img src="#" data-src="holder.js/100%x100%"  alt="not found"></div>
                                        <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists img-thumbnail"></div>
                                        <div class="m-t-20 text-center">
                                                    <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                                                        <span class="fileinput-new">choose</span>
                                                        <span class="fileinput-exists">change</span>
                                                        <input type="file" id="pb" name="pb" accept="image/*" class="form-control"></span>
                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning fileinput-exists"
                                               data-dismiss="fileinput">Entfernen</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

I chose `pb` as name for the actual file input. This is the controller function:

```
public function addUser(Request $request) {...}
```

Everything fine so far, `echo $request->pb` also echoes the filename as desired. HOWEVER, Laravel doesn't recognise this as a file apparently:

```
$request->file('pb')
```

returns null (yes, I have tried to display all files of `$request`, also `$request->hasFile()` returns false/null). I wonder why? Unfortunately, I cannot directly access `$_FILE` which would make things easier despite not being in the right order with Laravel in general.

Comment: make sure your form has ``enctype='multipart/form-data'``

Comment: @ahmad if you post this as an answer, you'll get this checked for the right! Thanks!

Comment: added as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your form has:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```